# Github, Can't Push To Upstream

Tags: git, netbeans, github, push, git-push

When I try to "Push..." on Netbeans, it gives me some steps to follow, the last of which is to select from an empty list of branches.

(I selected the only option (otigin) from the "Select Local Branches" option.

[image: Netbeans claiming that there are no branches.]

When I try "Push to upstream", it says that I haven't selected a branch!

I own the (private) repository. It has no content. I'd like to push an existing project to it in it's entirety.

Edit: I cannot use the command line for complicated reasons.

Comment: Well, that the remote repository is empty is the problem. Go to the command line and do `git push origin master` for the initial push, s.t. the `master` branch is created in the remote repository.

Comment: @filmor I can't access the command line. `dyld: Symbol not found:___strlcpy_chk, Referenced from: /usr/local/git/bin/git, Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib` :/

Comment: And that is the same git that is used by Netbeans? Isn't that installed somewhere in Netbeans' app-bundle? Maybe someone actually using OS X can help you better ;). Also, you could just do the initial pushing from a different machine...